# Spring - Problem converting a pojo to a JSON (No converter found error)

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud

**spring 4.3.3**

I'm trying to convert a Pojo to JSON, marking the Controller as a
@RestController, the problem with that is some elements are with first letter lower instead of upper case,

```
Ex:
"Id": 1, //This is ok  
"customerId": "1234", //Instead of CustomerId, this has customerId
...
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
...
public class CustomerController{
    ...
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public CustomerResponse postCustomerRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
```

I want that to be in upper case. The pojo is basically a xjc generated class from an xsd, and it contains,

```
@XmlElement(name = "Id")
protected int id;
@XmlElement(name = "CustomerId")
protected String customerId;
...
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int value) {
        this.id = value;
    }
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    public void setCustomerId(String value) {
        this.customerId = value;
    }
```

This has associated setter, getter for each attributes. In the Controller, I got ObjectMapper case insensitive set to true as well,

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
```

I also tried with, marking the Controller as @Controller instead of @RestController, provided @ResponseBody before the method,

**Controller**

```
@Controller
...
public class CustomerController {
...
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @ResponseBody
    public String postCustomerRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ...

//Used PropertyNamingStrategy with the ObjectMapper, converted the first character to an upper case, 
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true);
            ...
            CustomerResponse response=createCustomer(document,objectFactory);
            mapperObj.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomerJsonNameStrategy());
            String jsonOutput = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(response);
            return jsonOutput;
```

If I see the value of jsonOutput during debug in Eclipse, it outputs the json elements in correct case, but the response to the rest client is coming as,

```
{"errors": [{
   "message": "No converter found for return value of type: class java.lang.String",
   "type": "IllegalArgumentError"
}]}
```

Looks like the jackson serializier is interferring with the response and throwing the above error.

What's the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it to work by moving to an extension which doesn't have jackson setup. PS: This is in SAP Hybris and 
it contains multiple extensions/projects.

I marked the Controller with @Controller, added @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}), removed @ResponseBody, set the method return type as ResponseEntity, 
used a PropertyNamingStrategy to convert first letter in upper case.

```
public ResponseEntity<String> postCustomerRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    final org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper mapperObj = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
    CustomerResponse response=createCustomer(document,objectFactory);
    mapperObj.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomerJsonNameStrategy());

    final HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.setContentType(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(mapperObj.writeValueAsString(response), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring uses Jackson for converting POJO to json. Jackson by default makes first letter of field name small. If you wants custom names then add following jackson annotation.

```
@JsonProperty("CustomerId")
private String customerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Consumes does not help you very much in this case. It should be used to specify format of the input. Check this article:
http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/jax-rs-rest-consumes-example/

If you can see the jsonOutput during debug, your problem may be related to the way your client expects the output : your client may expect a JSON instead of a String object. 
Solution : return CustomerResponse instead of String.

```
@RestController
...
public class CustomerController {
  ...
  public CustomerResponse postCustomerRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) 
{
```

and CustomerResponse should have the fields annotated with @JsonProperty if you want to change the default naming.

```
@JsonProperty(name = "Id")
protected int id;

@JsonProperty(name = "CustomerId")
protected String customerId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would configure the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` with your custom property naming strategy, which is in IMHO the cleaner solution compared to serializing to json in every controller method

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        ...
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
        ...
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="propertyNamingStrategy" ref="customNamingStrategy" />
</bean
```

Or, you make sure that the `StringHttpMessageConverter` is registered as converter in your spring MVC config, if you really want or need to control the response body

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
     <mvc:message-converters>
            ...
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
            ...
   </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```